# Getting cookies with PHP curl

Tags: php, curl, cookies

I'm trying to get the *cookies* send by super simple script using the `curl`. Here are the files:

get_cookie.php:

```
...
$curl = curl_init("http://.../set_cookie.php");

$data = array('fname'=>"John", 'lname'=>"Brown");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data)); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
...
$response = curl_exec($curl);
...
// get cookies
preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $response, $matches);
$cookies = array();

foreach($matches[1] as $item) {
    parse_str($item, $cookie);
    $cookies = array_merge($cookies, $cookie);
}

echo "cookies recived: <br>";
var_dump($cookies);
```

set_cookie.php:

```
...
if (isset($_POST["fname"])) {
    setcookie("usr_name", "user_".$_POST["fname"], time()+60*60);
    ...
}
```

but on the curl response i get no cookies - the `$cookies` array is empty (I've checked - the `$_POST["fname"]` is set - the POST data was sent successfully ). When i call the `set_cookie` it the standard way - from the browser i get the desired *usr_name*
cookie. What's the problem with `curl`?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_COOKIELIST)` instead of parsing manually the response to get cookies?

see https://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html